# MongoDB free text search and highligthing

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search, text, solr

I have a certain amount of data, around 50k entities, and I need to implement free text search over two properties. My current situation is that there is MongoDB (Community Server) in my stack already. Right now I am deciding if I should start using Elasticsearch or Solr beside MongoDB. I would love to stick with MongoDB only, but I have some requirements. That is highlighting. I am browsing around MongoDB's docs and I've found this doc about [Atlas search highlighting](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/highlighting/). This is exactly what I need which is great. Problem is that it doesn't really work on my MongoDB server. There is also nothing about highlighting under [text search docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

I am confused. Could someone please explain current situation regarding free text search and highlighting with MongoDB. Is it supported or not? Is it Atlas only? What is the current status?

Comment: Atlas search only exists in atlas.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> My current situation is that there is MongoDB (Community Server) in my stack already. Right now I am deciding if I should start using Elasticsearch or Solr beside MongoDB

It's good that you explored other options. I strongly suggest to use pure search solutions for this use case[free text search, highlighting] i.e ES, Solr. Both serves better in terms of search. One product cannot solve all the use cases.

> I would love to stick with MongoDB only, but I have some requirements.

Mongo DB is case sensitive. And only atlas provides search. Same highlighting can also be achieved in other search solutions i.e ES, Solr.

If you still want to stick with Atlas, I would suggest you to do a minimal POC with your use case in atlas against ES/SOLR.

Comment: I am not planning to use Atlas at all since it is not free on premiss. At the moment I am running MongoDB Community Server. If this won't satisfy my needs, then I will use Elastic or Solr. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Is there any reason why only Atlas provides search?

Comment: It's the difference between commercial and open source. Not only search, atlas also provides security at different levels which is useful for RBAC.

Comment: @Nice-Guy Basic search application should provide highlighting and search always means case insensitive. Solr, ES also provides the same. No need of highlighting  these points IMO.

Comment: What do you mean. You literally wrote, "Mongo DB is case sensitive." That is false so I pointed out the fact. If you store application data in MongoDB, and you want search on the same data, you should at least consider Atlas Search. It does offer a free tier, too. The power of Solr and ES is Lucene, the same engine in MongoDB Atlas Search.

Comment: I meant the difference between open source and atlas.

Comment: there is no Atlas Search in open source at all

Comment: Yes that's what I am also saying. Probably you missed something here.